# Linking HTML to a CSS class

Tags: html, css

I'm not the best at HTML. Essentially I am trying to get the effect of a lot of line breaks, without filling my code with a lot of consecutive `<br>` tags. What I have in my head is this CSS:

```
.movedown {
    position: relative;
    down: 120px;
}
```

and this HTML, where my text is:

```
<span class="movedown">*text here*</span>
```

I only need it on a single page. Anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Well for starters what you have isn't css. There is no down property nor does css take brs in it...

Comment: Down is not a valid atribute for css. What do you want to achieve with it?

Comment: Google margin and padding properties, those may give you the effect you're looking for.

Comment: use position absolute and top instead of down. Or keep relative and use margin-top. Read some tutorials on CSS and HTML, it's not that hard!?

Comment: Why not just use a bunch of separate `p` tags?

Comment: its not about being best but knowing stuff is better you may start form MDN or [codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/web)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 .movedown {
        position: relative; //Not required
        margin-top: 120px;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you want to inject *lots of breaks* between two words you can inject a span tag styled as follows:

```css
.long-br {
    display: block;
    height: 12em; /* 12em is roughly 10 lines at current font size/1.2 line height */
}
```

```html
<p>Hello <span class="long-br"></span> World</p>
```

Alternate: if you want to insert *lots of breaks* between two blocks of text, the ideal way is to use margins:

```css
.long-gap {
    margin-top: 12em;  
}
```

```html
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p class="long-gap">Paragraph 2</p>
```

Comment: Do you really think it wise to point him in the em direction when he doesn't have a clue of what css is....

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the CSS property **margin-top** to add some space without using line breaks.

```
    .movedown {
        margin-top: 120px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`down` is not an existing css rule. What you should be using is a `div` with `margin-top`, this creates a space above the element.

```css
.down {
  margin-top: 50px; 
}
```

```html
*top text*
<div class="down">*text here*</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'down' try:

```
top:120px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `<div>` elements instead of `<span>`.

By default `div` is a block style element and `span` is inline.

`block` occupies the whole row, so each new one will be on a new row.

You can change the default behaviour with CSS but better to get a grip of the basic elements first.